# Bash Shell Script - Check for a flag and grab its value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I am trying to make a shell script which is designed to be run like this:

```
script.sh -t application
```

Firstly, in my script I want to check to see if the script has been run with the -t flag. For example if it has been run without the flag like this I want it to error:

```
script.sh
```

Secondly, assuming there is a -t flag, I want to grab the value and store it in a variable that I can use in my script for example like this:

```
FLAG="application"
```

So far the only progress I've been able to make on any of this is that $@ grabs all the command line arguments but I don't know how this relates to flags, or if this is even possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse command line arguments in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You should read this [getopts](https://archive.is/TRzn4) tutorial.

Example with `-a` switch that requires an argument :

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Like greybot said(`getopt` != `getopts`) :

> The external command getopt(1) is never safe to use, unless you *know*
>   it is GNU getopt, you call it in a GNU-specific way, *and* you ensure
>   that GETOPT_COMPATIBLE is not in the environment. Use getopts (shell
>   builtin) instead, or simply loop over the positional parameters.

Comment: `getopts` is a `bash` built-in, but there is also an external `getopt` program that should work with any POSIX-compatible shell.

Comment: The external command getopt(1) is never safe to use, unless you *know* it is GNU getopt, you call it in a GNU-specific way, *and* you ensure that GETOPT_COMPATIBLE is not in the environment. Use getopts (shell builtin) instead, or simply loop over the positional parameters.

Comment: Sorry I need this dumbed down for me. If it is a bash built in will it work for shell in debian

Comment: The `getopts` tutorial is simple and provides helpful examples.  Definitely worth reading if you come across this post.

Comment: Agreed with previous comments: the getopts tutorial is seriously worth the time spent reading it, including the comments, some of which are providing advanced/alternative usages.

Answer (score 41):

Use `$#` to grab the number of arguments, if it is unequal to 2 there are not enough arguments provided:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
   usage;
fi
```

Next, check if `$1` equals `-t`, otherwise an unknown flag was used:

```
if [ "$1" != "-t" ]; then
  usage;
fi
```

Finally store `$2` in `FLAG`:

```
FLAG=$2
```

Note: `usage()` is some function showing the syntax. For example:

```
function usage {
   cat << EOF
Usage: script.sh -t <application>

Performs some activity
EOF
   exit 1
}
```

Comment: This may works, but what happens when I want to use multiple flags?

Comment: It becomes more complex and it makes more sense to use the getopts command as described by the [answer of @GillesQuenot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447471/246263)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a generalized simple command argument interface you can paste to the top of all your scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A flags
declare -A booleans
args=()

while [ "$1" ];
do
    arg=$1
    if [ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ]
    then
      shift
      rev=$(echo "$arg" | rev)
      if [ -z "$1" ] || [ "${1:0:1}" == "-" ] || [ "${rev:0:1}" == ":" ]
      then
        bool=$(echo ${arg:1} | sed s/://g)
        booleans[$bool]=true
        echo \"$bool\" is boolean
      else
        value=$1
        flags[${arg:1}]=$value
        shift
        echo \"$arg\" is flag with value \"$value\"
      fi
    else
      args+=("$arg")
      shift
      echo \"$arg\" is an arg
    fi
done


echo -e "\n"
echo booleans: ${booleans[@]}
echo flags: ${flags[@]}
echo args: ${args[@]}

echo -e "\nBoolean types:\n\tPrecedes Flag(pf): ${booleans[pf]}\n\tFinal Arg(f): ${booleans[f]}\n\tColon Terminated(Ct): ${booleans[Ct]}\n\tNot Mentioned(nm): ${boolean[nm]}"
echo -e "\nFlag: myFlag => ${flags["myFlag"]}"
echo -e "\nArgs: one: ${args[0]}, two: ${args[1]}, three: ${args[2]}"
```

By running the command:

```
bashScript.sh firstArg -pf -myFlag "my flag value" secondArg -Ct: thirdArg -f
```

The output will be this:

```
"firstArg" is an arg
"pf" is boolean
"-myFlag" is flag with value "my flag value"
"secondArg" is an arg
"Ct" is boolean
"thirdArg" is an arg
"f" is boolean


booleans: true true true
flags: my flag value
args: firstArg secondArg thirdArg

Boolean types:
    Precedes Flag(pf): true
    Final Arg(f): true
    Colon Terminated(Ct): true
    Not Mentioned(nm): 

Flag: myFlag => my flag value

Args: one => firstArg, two => secondArg, three => thirdArg
```

Basically, the arguments are divided up into flags booleans and generic arguments.
By doing it this way a user can put the flags and booleans anywhere as long as he/she keeps the generic arguments (if there are any) in the specified order.

**Allowing me and now you to never deal with bash argument parsing again!**

**You can view an updated script [here](https://github.com/jozsefmorrissey/BashScripts/blob/master/commandParser.sh) (more complex and useful)**

This has been enormously useful over the last year. It can now simulate scope by prefixing the variables with a scope parameter.

This creates a function specific argument, flag & bool object.

```
replace() (
  source ./commandParser.sh -scope ${FUNCNAME[0]} "$@"
  echo "$replaceArgs"
  echo a=${replaceFlags["a"]}
  echo b is ${replaceBooleans["b"]}
)

replace arg1 -a 'alpha' arg2 -b: arg3
```

Output:

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 
a=alpha
b is true
```

Comment: This is a great answer: I take it one step further by placing it in a script which I then alias as arg_handler in my .bashrc file. Then at the top of every script I paste:
`source arg_handler; arg_handler "$@"`

Comment: Shouldn't -pf be two separate flags though, as it is not proceeded by 2 dashes? As in p and f.

Comment: THANK YOU! James, for what ever reason I never realized that  a single - was for single character flags and a '--' was for multi char flags. Seriously thanks i feel so stupid for not seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try shFlags -- Advanced command-line flag library for Unix shell scripts.

https://github.com/kward/shflags

It is very good and very flexible.

FLAG TYPES: This is a list of the DEFINE_*'s that you can do.  All flags take
a name, default value, help-string, and optional 'short' name (one-letter
name).  Some flags have other arguments, which are described with the flag.

DEFINE_string: takes any input, and intreprets it as a string.

DEFINE_boolean: typically does not take any argument: say --myflag to set
FLAGS_myflag to true, or --nomyflag to set FLAGS_myflag to false.
Alternately, you can say
--myflag=true  or --myflag=t or --myflag=0  or
--myflag=false or --myflag=f or --myflag=1
Passing an option has the same affect as passing the option once.

DEFINE_float: takes an input and intreprets it as a floating point number. As
shell does not support floats per-se, the input is merely validated as
being a valid floating point value.

DEFINE_integer: takes an input and intreprets it as an integer.

SPECIAL FLAGS: There are a few flags that have special meaning:
--help (or -?)  prints a list of all the flags in a human-readable fashion
--flagfile=foo  read flags from foo.  (not implemented yet)
--              as in getopt(), terminates flag-processing

EXAMPLE USAGE:

```
-- begin hello.sh --
 ! /bin/sh
. ./shflags
DEFINE_string name 'world' "somebody's name" n
FLAGS "$@" || exit $?
eval set -- "${FLAGS_ARGV}"
echo "Hello, ${FLAGS_name}."
-- end hello.sh --

$ ./hello.sh -n Kate
Hello, Kate.
```

Note: I took this text from shflags documentation