# In Bash, why does using getopts in a function only work once?

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to create a simple function on macOS Sierra that counts the characters in a string. This works fine (added to my `bashrc` file):

```
function cchar() {
    str=$1
    len=${#str}
    echo "string is $len char long"
}

$ cchar "foo"
string is 3 char long
```

I'm trying to expand it with a `-a` option, so I added this to my function (and commented the rest out for testing):

```
while getopts "a:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        a)
            echo "-a param: $OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

After some testing while writing this, I've noticed everytime I run `cchar -a "test"`, I have to run it without options (`cchar`) otherwise the next time I run it with the `-a` option, it doesn't recognise the option.

```
$ cchar

$ cchar -a "foo"
-a param: foo

$ cchar -a "foo"

$ cchar

$ cchar -a "foo"
-a param: foo
```

Comment: My end goal is to have the `-a` option only return the string count as an int, for use in other functions. I came upon this issue while trying to do that.

Comment: I tried `unset opt` after the `while` loop in case the var is remembered between after the function ends, didn't fix it.

Also, different redirections had no positive effect (`&2>1`, `>&1`, [blank])

Comment: Redirections are not command-line options. Why would they affect anything?

Comment: In the 4th line of my second code block. Since that wasn't echoing, I thought there could be a problem there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reset the variable `OPTIND`, which keeps track of the current positional argument number. It should suffice to make that variable local to your function.

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: See [getopts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-getopts) in the Bash manual.  It says, in part: _Each time it is invoked, getopts places the next option in the shell variable `name`, initializing `name` if it does not exist, and the index of the next argument to be processed into the variable OPTIND. OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked. … The shell does not reset OPTIND automatically; it must be manually reset between multiple calls to getopts within the same shell invocation if a new set of parameters is to be used._

Comment: Yes, `getopts` is designed for parsing script options, not function arguments. But it will work just as well with local variables (although `local OPTIND=1` is probably better, just in case.)

Comment: What would be a better way to handle function arguments?

Comment: @trav: getopts is just fine. I use it a lot. I was trying to explain the failure to initialize OPTIND.

Comment: Plus one for the local variable override.

Answer (score 0):

The final code I ended up using:

```
# Count characters in a string
function cchar() {
    local OPTIND

    while getopts "a:" opt; do
        case $opt in
            a)
                echo ${#OPTARG}
                return
                ;;
        esac
    done

    echo "string is ${#1} characters long"
}

$ cchar "foo bar"
string is 7 characters long

$ cchar -a "foo bar"
7
```

Note: I had to use `return` in lieu of `exit`, when sourced from `.bashrc`, `exit` will close the current shell.

Comment: Note that you could simply use: `echo "string is ${#1} char long"` in the long form (and `echo "${#OPTARG}" >&2` in the short form).  Is there a good reason to write to standard error in the short form?  It would be more usual to write to standard output — you can then redirect the output to standard error when you invoke the function if that's what you need.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I was writing to stderr because [the accepted answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447406/bash-shell-script-check-for-a-flag-and-grab-its-value) used it.